# How to write Column(TypeName="Date") in Fluent FluentValidation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

we can say [Column(TypeName="Date")] using dataannotations.

Similarly using Fluent Validation, How we can write this?
https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html

Comment: What the type of the property ?

Comment: Are you wanting to validate the user has entered a date with no time component? Please clarify your question.